# USB drive says it's full but it is not

Tags: linux

I have about 12k pictures that I am copying over to a USB drive.  I am using rsync to do this.

```
time rsync -avh /tmp/oldPictures/jpg /mnt/USB/
```

The total size of all the pictures is about 40GB the USB drive is a 64GB USB drive.

I have formatted the drive and started over.  I am formatting the drive in vfat so that I can use it on a windows machine.  When it reaches to about 5,000 pictures it stops copying.  The rsync does not error out or anything it just stays there and does not continue to copy anymore.  From the log files I see the error that says the drive is out of space.  When I do an df -h on the drive it is only 22% full.  Also NO other partition is even close to being out space.  I am running CentOS 7 and it is updated.

Not sure what to do from here.  Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df -ih`? Usually when I see drive full errors when there is still space on the drive it is caused by the partition running out of inodes.

Comment: Are all the files in a single directory?  Don't remember the exact details but  FAT has a smallish limit to the number of items that can be in a single directory.

Comment: @Thegs they said the filesystem was vFAT, so  not inodes.

Comment: Is the USB drive from a trustable source? There are fake drives on the market...

Comment: Is your vFAT block size too large for the files?

Comment: All the files are in a single directory.  I bought the USB drive at a local respectable store and according to df -h it says it is 64GB.  How can I check my VFat block size?

Comment: @Zoredache Oh wow, I didn't know that! I'll read up a bit more on how vFAT works, thanks!